# Should dummy variables be allowed to correlate (R code & data provided)

Tags: r, regression, multivariate-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

**tl;dr:** What is the difference between a regression model that allows its dummy variables to be correlated and one that doesn't do so? For example, how does that affect Standard Error of the regression coefficients (coefs)?

In my reproducible SEM (*structural equation model*) `modelA` below, imagine I remove the `Group_HI ~~ 0*Group_MT` (denoting `correlation bet. two dummies is 0`) altogether leading to `modelB`. What is the difference between a model that uses `Group_HI ~~ 0*Group_MT` (`modelA`) and one that doesn't include anything to describe the relation between `Group_HI` and `Group_MT` (`modelB`)?

Specifically, it seems `modelB` produces Standard Errors for coefs that are closer to those given by a MANOVA:

```
summary(lm(cbind(MP,SE)~Group,data=d)) 

Response MP :
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   4.6667     0.6150   7.588 8.19e-10 ***
GroupHI       3.1833     0.8136   3.913 0.000281 ***  ## This SE
GroupMT       6.7451     0.8438   7.994 1.95e-10 ***  ## This SE

Response SE :
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   4.2000     0.3378  12.432  < 2e-16 ***
GroupHI       2.1500     0.4469   4.811 1.48e-05 *** ## This SE
GroupMT       3.7412     0.4635   8.071 1.49e-10 *** ## This SE
```

But `modelA` produces Standard Errors for coefs that are closer to those given by:

```
stacked_DVs <- pivot_longer(d, c(MP,SE), names_to = "DV")
coef(summary(lm(value~DV*Group-1,data = stacked_DVs)))

              Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
DVMP          4.666667  0.4961705  9.405370 2.364383e-15
DVSE          4.200000  0.4961705  8.464833 2.559422e-13
GroupHI       3.183333  0.6563718  4.849893 4.648941e-06   ## This SE
GroupMT       6.745098  0.6807403  9.908475 1.912183e-16   ## This SE
```

**Reproducible data and R code:**

```
library(tidyverse); library(fastDummies) ; library(lavaan)

d <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/v/main/memory.csv")
d <- dummy_cols(d, "Group")[-5]

modelA <- "MP ~ Group_HI
   SE ~  Group_HI
   MP ~  Group_MT
   SE ~  Group_MT
 Group_HI ~~ 0*Group_MT  #Question: what is the effect of removing this line on SE of coefs? (See `modelB`)
   MP ~~ MP
   SE ~~ SE
   MP ~~ SE"

summary(sem(modelA, data = d, meanstructure = TRUE))

Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  MP ~                                                
    Group_HI          3.183    0.659    4.830    0.000   ## This SE
  SE ~                                                
    Group_HI          2.150    0.362    5.938    0.000
  MP ~                                                
    Group_MT          6.745    0.684    9.868    0.000   ## This SE
  SE ~                                                
    Group_MT          3.741    0.375    9.963    0.000



modelB <- "MP ~ Group_HI
   SE ~  Group_HI
   MP ~  Group_MT
   SE ~  Group_MT
### Group_HI ~~ 0*Group_MT  #This line removed.
   MP ~~ MP
   SE ~~ SE
   MP ~~ SE"

summary(sem(modelB, data = d, meanstructure = TRUE))

Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  MP ~                                                
    Group_HI          3.183    0.790    4.031    0.000  ## This SE
  SE ~                                                
    Group_HI          2.150    0.434    4.956    0.000  ## This SE
  MP ~                                                
    Group_MT          6.745    0.819    8.235    0.000  ## This SE
  SE ~                                                
    Group_MT          3.741    0.450    8.315    0.000  ## This SE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't include the correlation, your model is wrong. Here's what you included.

```
Covariances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
 .MP ~~                                               
   .SE               -0.607    0.416   -1.458    0.145
```

That's why, in Model B, lavaan includes that parameter by default, even if you don't ask for it. The correlations of your predictors are not considered part of you model (they're not used for the calculation of the null model.

ML in SEMs doesn't do a great job with smaller samples. There are also differences that happen when you divide by N, or N - 1, and I forget what programs do, but this will cause problems.

When you stack the DVs, you violate the independence assumption. You can fix this using lmer::lmer:

```
library(lme4)
stacked_DVs <- pivot_longer(d, c(MP,SE), names_to = "DV")
summary(lmer(value~DV*Group-1 + (1 | ID),data = stacked_DVs, REML = FALSE))
```

But the differences are small.

Comment: Jeremy, thank you so much!  Why `if we don't include the correlation between dummies, our model is wrong?`  What is specifically wrong with that? Levels of `Group` are independent but their dummies are not?

Comment: The dummies are correlated. :)  Unless you have set up the data collection to ensure that they are exactly zero. So if you don't correlate them, the model is wrong and the parameter estimates should are biased (even if the model fits).

Comment: Thanks! To be clear, *with* or *without* dummies being correlated:  `.MP ~~.SE` will be `-0.607 (SE = 0.416)`. So, I'm not clear why you stated: *"That's why, in Model B, lavaan includes that parameter by default, even if you don't ask for it."*, would you mind adding a bit more clarification to your answer?